# Parse: how to determine if any given user is anonymous?

Tags: parse-platform, anonymous

If we are dealing with the current user, it is easy by doing:

```
ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
```

But what if I just have bunch of usernames? How can I determine which ones are anonymous? I have tried querying the `User` table like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryUser = new ParseUser().getQuery();
queryUser.whereEqualTo("User", usernameString);
queryUser.setLimit(1);
queryUser.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            if (users != null) {
                for (ParseUser user : users) {
                    // do a check
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And tried different ways to do the check but nothing seems to work. For example:

```
ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(user)
```

always returns `false`. I have also tried accessing the `authData` as `String`:

```
String authData = user.getString("authData");
if (authData == null) Log.i("authData", "null");
else Log.i("authData", authData);
```

but always get `null`. I have also tried casting it as `JSONObject` hoping to see if I can determine if an `anonymous` field exists in the JSON:

```
JSONObject authDataJson = (JSONObject) user.get("authData");
```

but also always get `null`.

How can I determine if any given username belongs to an anonymous user? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info. Is this a cloud function you trying to create? Are you using parse-server or parse.com? what SDK version etc.

Comment: I'm doing this from an android app. I'm querying a requests table to show its contents in a ListView. Each request has a username and location. Where a user is non-anonymous, showing its username is fine. But if it is anonymous, I wish to show the string "Anonymous" instead mainly for esthetics since an anonymous user gets a username like "m57jBjPLCeSAmdfm85kvQySoe" which is an eyesore if nothing else. I'm using parse 1.13.0. Thx

Comment: I have this problem